# Whats the best way to extract every entry Fields from CSV file

Tags: c++, csv

I have a CSV file that contains different rows i.e. Identifier, Title, publisher, and Authors1, Authors2... etc.

Now, I'm trying to extract every field one by one and store it into their proper data sets. For example: I'm storing the title in String, year in int like that.

[This is the CSV file I'm learning on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx56x.png)
As I'm trying to implement this in C++. The problem is that There is a total of 10 separate Author fields with a varying number of authors. How can I design a loop in which it firsts identify the total entries of Authors then start the copy in into some linked List or arrays etc.

```
int main(){

ifstream myFile("BibtexFileCSV.csv");

if(!myFile.is_open()){
    cout<<"File failed to open"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

string identifier;
string title;
string journal;
string month;
string year;
string publisher;
string author;

string line;

while(getline(myFile, line)){

    string chars="{}""";
    for (char c: chars){
        line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), c), line.end());
        line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(),line.end(),'\"'),line.end());
    }

    stringstream ss(line);
    getline(ss, identifier, ',');
    getline(ss, title, ',' );
    getline(ss, journal, ',');
    getline(ss, month, ',');
    getline(ss, year, ',');
    getline(ss, publisher, ',');

    vector <string> authors;

    string lastName;
    string firstName;

    int i=0;
    while(i <= 1 ){
        getline(ss, author, ',');
        authors.push_back(author);
        i++;
    }       

    cout<<publisher +" : ";
    for (unsigned int j=0; j < 2; j++){

        string n = authors.at(j);

        stringstream names(n);

        getline(names, lastName, ' ');
        getline(names, firstName);
        cout<<firstName;
    }

    cout<<firstName;
    cout<<" "+lastName;
    cout<<endl;
}

myFile.close();
return 0;
```

}

I can implement this task without using any formal loops but it will become a mess and requires a ton of lines of code.

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but maybe [unordered_set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) or [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) can help?

Comment: Brother, this is the CSV file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx56x.png I'm trying to make a code that can read all the Author fields from 1 to 10 and copy the entries into some linked list or array.

Comment: You should look at `std::cin`. You might parse each line into it variables as easily as something like `cin >> title >> journal >> month >> year` etc... and group them with a `typedef` and then add them to a vector, or a set.

Comment: If an author is listed 5 times, do you want its name 5 times or only once in your list/array?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way you can go for is to create a function for similar actions. For example, you repeat the stringstream a lot of times to split each element into its' own. Better do a function

```
auto explode(const string& s, const char& c) -> vector<string>
{
    string buff{ "" };
    vector<string> v;

    for (auto n : s)
    {
        if (n != c) buff += n; else
            if (n == c && buff != "") { v.push_back(buff); buff = ""; }
    }
    if (buff != "") v.push_back(buff);

    return v;
}
```

Then you can reuse the function. Another thing to make your life easier, you know you have more than 1 row in this CSV and you need a vector or some sort of array to store all the information from the CSV, prepare a structure/class with some proper name that matches your CSV's purpose in singular, then add your own properties and create operator to input into the structure/class.

The algorithm can be:

- Go once through the headers (eg. ID, Name, Author, etc.)
- Loop until the file has reached its' end
- Get each row of the CSV with the delimiter and use the above function to split each column into array/vector of strings.
- Use your own operator to input into the structure/class

Benefits:

- The code will be easier to understand
- A bit shorter
- Simplier

Cons:

- Hard to understand for a beginner

I will give now the other option, procedural-style code.

```
vector<string> lines;

  fstream file;
  file.open("book.csv");

  string line
  while (getline( file, line,'\n'))
    {
      istringstream templine(line); 
      string data;

      while (getline(templine, data,','))
        lines.push_back(data);  

    }
  file.close();
```

With the above code, you open the file, create temporary variable named `line` to store each row, then iterate once again every string before the delimiter `,` is met.

And a third option, you can go for third-party CSV parsing libraries.

Such are:

- https://github.com/d99kris/rapidcsv
- https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL